# Can REDCap adjust for business days?

Tags: redcap

I am creating a REDCap project where follow-up calls must be made at set intervals after a patient is discharged (1 week, 2 weeks, 1 month, 2 months, 3 months, 6 months, 9 months, 1 year, 1.5 years).

I am using @CALCDATE (for example, to get the 1 week date I used  @CALCDATE([discharge_date],7,'d')), which works great but the project team wants to account for business days as they will only be doing calls on business days. In Excel, I use WORKDAY.

I can't find anything about REDCap and business days anywhere but I don't know if it's because it's not possible or I just can't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Fairly sure this isn't possible without using an external module. If you're using longitudinal data collection, most versions of REDCap automatically come with the Scheduling module installed. This allows you set Days Offset (1 week post-discharge, 2 weeks, etc.) *and* an offset range. Set the offset range to plus/minus 2 days so that even if a follow-up call is scheduled on a Saturday, it can be completed Thursday, Friday or the following Monday. Might work for your purposes depending on study design :)